# How to meet Bullet requirement for rosdep tf2_bullet? Or can I trick rosdep?

Tags: ros, bullet, wheezy, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to do a ROS install on Raspbian (pi). 3.10.25+

Pretty much everything has gone very well until I tried to install the tf2_bullet package that I need for create_node.

To install new packages I have been following the instructions here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20Hydro%20on%20RaspberryPi#Installing_new_packages

Running

```
rosdep install  --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y --os=debian:wheezy
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
tf2_bullet: No definition of [bullet] for OS version [wheezy]
```

I have manually installed bullet on my system from source (although I'm not sure I did it right).

I've already checked and create_node does in fact need tf, which depends on tf2 down to bullet.

I see in the source for rosdep that it does a look up in the data dictionary passed in to RosdepDefinition, but I haven't yet found where that data dictionary is created.

Anyone know how to get bullet installed or how I can get rosdep to move past this point?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142421/how-to-meet-bullet-requirement-for-rosdep-tf2_bullet?-or-can-i-trick-rosdep?/) by [csherstan](https://answers.ros.org/users/9751/csherstan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2014-03-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a pull request open for adding command line support to ignore specific keys in rosdep:
https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/301

What you can do to ignore the `bullet` rosdep key is providing an empty definition for it locally.

Create the file `/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/10-local.list` with contents:

```
yaml file:///etc/ros/rosdep/local.yaml
```

And create the file `/etc/ros/rosdep/local.yaml` with contents:

```
bullet:
  debian:
    wheezy: []
```

Then execute `rosdep update` and try again.

To get this permanently fixed, if you figure out what package to install, you could also file a pull request to change the definition for weezy in this file: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml#L304-L306

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [csherstan](https://answers.ros.org/users/9751/csherstan/) on 2014-03-23**:
Seems ok. It let me keep going, but not sure what it might affect.

**Comment by [hcostelha](https://answers.ros.org/users/839/hcostelha/) on 2014-05-30**:
It might be even better to do  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list  , and add
bullet:
debian:
wheezy:
apt:
packages:
- libbullet-dev
to the yaml file.